# Cypress API testing : How to access data generated from it block to another it block

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I access the token generated from 1st `it` block to 2nd `it` block.

here is the code:

1st it block

```
      it('Login using new user', () => {
        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/v1/user/login",
          body: 
          {
          "mobile_number": "+9912345678"
          "password": "p@ssword"  
          }

        })
          .then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        })
          .then((response) => {
            const bearer_token = response.body.data.user.access_token.token // 
*in here where I get and put the token in var bearer_token*

            cy.log("Bearer token: " + token )
        })
      })
```

2nd it block

```
     it('Create New Mobile', () => {
        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/v1/user/add_new_mobile_numbers",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token // *in here where I put the token*
          },
          body: 
          {
            "mobile_prefix": "+991",
            "mobile_number": "9912345679"
          }
})
```

I login from 1st block, then i need to use the token to add new mobile num in 2nd block.
in cypress dashboard it returns an error:
`token is not defined`

Comment: Hi. To share data between tests you might opt for a global context variable in the same spec file, or use `localStorage` to store your token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ideal to save to a test environment variable via `Cypress.env()`, since they persist across the test boundary.

```js
it('Login using new user', () => {
  cy.api(...)
    .then((response) => {
      const token = response.body.data.user.access_token.token

      // store env var
      Cypress.env('token', token)               
    })

...
it('Create New Mobile', () => {
  cy.api({
...
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${Cypress.env('token')}`  // use env var 
...
```

See [Environment Variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables)